# Get an item in Seq using UInt

Tags: scala, chisel

I'm trying to write a cache memory, so I created a `Seq` of type `Mem` because I'm trying to have access to all elements in a set of the cache at the same time.

```
val metaMem = Seq.fill(nWays) (Mem((nSets), new MetaData))
```

and then I want to have indexing like below:

```
   metaMem(way).write(set, MD)
```

But, because, way is `UInt` in my code, and seq only accepts `Int` for indexing, it would cause compile error.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically to access a hardware element using a dynamic value in a `UInt` you must use a `Vec`. The easiest way in a case like this is to create a `Vec` by using `VecInit` which, given a seq, defines the `Vec` and wires up your elements.

**But** Memories are not a subclass of Data (as is required by `Vec`/`VecInit`).
Here is a very naive example of a simple module that creates a bank of memories and provides read/write access to them.

```
/** Simulate a VecLike bank of memories
  */
class MemBank(val banks: Int, val bankDepth: Int) extends MultiIOModule {
  val bank = IO(Input(UInt(16.W)))
  val address = IO(Input(UInt(16.W)))
  val isRead = IO(Input(Bool()))
  val inputValue = IO(Input(UInt(32.W)))
  val outputValue = IO(Output(UInt(32.W)))

  val mems = Seq.fill(banks) { Mem(bankDepth, UInt(32.W)) }

  outputValue := DontCare

  when(isRead) {
    (0 until banks).foldLeft(when(false.B) {}) {
      case (whenContext, bankIndex) =>
        whenContext.elsewhen(bank === bankIndex.U) {
          outputValue := mems(bankIndex)(address)
        }
    }
  }.otherwise {
    (0 until banks).foldLeft(when(false.B) {}) {
      case (whenContext, bankIndex) =>
        whenContext.elsewhen(bank === bankIndex.U) {
          mems(bankIndex)(address) := inputValue
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is a UnitTest that can demonstrate using this module

```
class MemBankTest extends FreeSpec with ChiselScalatestTester {

  "MemBankSimulation should work" in {
    test(new MemBank(banks = 3, bankDepth = 3)) { dut =>
      // write values into memory
      dut.isRead.poke(false.B)
      for (bank <- 0 until dut.banks) {
        for (address <- 0 until dut.bankDepth) {
          dut.clock.step()
          dut.bank.poke(bank.U)
          dut.address.poke(address.U)
          dut.inputValue.poke((bank * 1000 + address).U)
        }
      }

      // read values out of memory banks
      dut.isRead.poke(true.B)
      for (bank <- 0 until dut.banks) {
        for (address <- 0 until dut.bankDepth) {
          dut.clock.step()
          dut.bank.poke(bank.U)
          dut.address.poke(address.U)
          println(f"Bank $bank%3d at address $address%3d contains ${dut.outputValue.peek().litValue()}%6d")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are a lot of other ways to do this and I would encourage you to look at other chisel projects like rocket-chip to see how multiple memories are handled.
It would still be good to see how this approach works. It creates a `Seq` of `Mem` but it use foldLeft (a very useful method) to create a set of `Mux`es that select the bank you are interested in. There are two parallel uses of this to control reading and writing separately.
I hope this helps, this is a good and tough question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. However, it gives me error:
overloaded method value apply with alternatives(...) cannot be applied to (Seq[chisel3.Mem[memory.cache.MetaData]])

Comment: Hmm, it looks like the error is because `Mem` is not a subclass of Data, I will dig a bit deeper to see how this is done in practice

Comment: I have updated the answer to something that works for memories. I think there is a small issue with accessing the final element of the last memory, but it should not be hard to debug

Comment: Wow, what a nice solution. Thanks a lot. Could you please explain a bit about when(false.B){} and the way you used the "case"?

Comment: `foldLeft` starts with a seed value. In this is case I pass the seed as `when(false.B){}` which returns a `WhenContext`. `foldLeft` calls a function I provide which takes two arguments, the first argument is the last value computed by the function (which in the first iteration is the seed), the other argument is the next value in the list you are iterating over, `case (a,b) => ...` is just the way you express the function `foldLeft` needs

Comment: Each call of the function calls the `elsewhen` method of the previous `WhenContext` and returns a new `WhenContext` to be used for the next value. Hope that helps